# Correct bubble sort in JS doesn't do anything

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

The code just logs the same array. What seems to be wrong here? I'm using VS Code.

```js
function bubbleSort(array) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < array.length - 1 - i; j++) {
      if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) {
        [array[j], array[j + 1] = array[j + 1], array[j]];
      }
    }
  }
  return array;
}

let arr1 = [9, 4, 6, 4, 3];

console.log(bubbleSort(arr1));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
[array[j], array[j + 1]] = [array[j + 1], array[j]];
```

instead of:

```
[array[j], array[j + 1] = array[j + 1], array[j]];
```

Pay close attention to where the square brackets begin and end.

---

Your current code:

1. assigns one array index to itself
2. creates an array with 3 elements
3. and throws it away immediately

What you actually want is a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). (thanks to @Reyno for the link!)